# Unit Test Fail with longer number in calculator example

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing

Unit Test in WPF project. I'm starting Unit Testing and am not sure why the second of the two tests fails.

If I try a smaller number, as per the first test, it works, is there a numerical limit that I might need to know or could it be an error related to something else? *AddMoreDifficult* passes, *AddEvenMoreDifficult* fails and gives the result of *988302965*

**Test that passes**

```
public void AddMoreDifficult()
{
    calculator.KeyCommand.Execute("10000");
    calculator.AddCommand.Execute(null);
    calculator.KeyCommand.Execute("24756");
    calculator.EquateCommand.Execute(null);

    Assert.AreEqual(34756, calculator.CurrentValue);
}
```

**Test that fails**

```
[TestMethod]
public void AddEvenMoreDifficult()
{
    calculator.KeyCommand.Execute("9578237555");
    calculator.AddCommand.Execute(null);
    calculator.KeyCommand.Execute("2");
    calculator.EquateCommand.Execute(null);

    Assert.AreEqual(9578237557, calculator.CurrentValue);
}
```

Notes:

This crops up in [Unit Testing Part 2](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/Getting-Started-with-Unit-Testing-Part-2?ocid=relatedentry) 14 minutes in but is skipped over.

Comment: what is the data type of `CurrentValue`?

Comment: Was not sure if it was an easy fix, full code can be downloaded here from the tutorial: https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=b5e716c9beefc8b4&id=B5E716C9BEEFC8B4%2119461

Comment: Datatype I'd assume is numberic as it's a WPF calculator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because of an integer overflow. The calculator stores the `currentValue` as in integer, and when `KeyCommand.Execute("9578237555")` is called, it does this:

```
int currentValue = 0; // this is previously set
string keyString = "9578237555";

foreach (char key in keyString.ToString())
{
    if (!char.IsDigit(key))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid key", "key");
    }

    currentValue = (currentValue * 10) + (int)char.GetNumericValue(key);
}
```

So it will increase the `currentValue` by a factor of 10 until it hits its maximum. You can see this if you print out the `currentValue` after its assignment:

```
9
95
957
9578
95782
957823
9578237
95782375
957823755
988302963
```

Unfortunately, this type of overflow does not generate an exception. If you change the type to long, the test will work fine.

Comment: This will work up the Int64.MaxValue, better use BigInteger to make sure!

Comment: @indofraiser Absolutely, and I understand your concerns after seeing this happen in a video entitled “Getting started with Unit Testing” where the instructor just goes over this error with a “oh, I can’t do math” (even more so after adding 2 to a number >_>)… It kind of defeats unit tests if we just start excusing failed tests with “I probably just wasn’t able to set the expected value correctly” :/